# How to fetch datas from cosmos DB result which contains $t and $v

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on an API which fetch data from cosmos DB. While fetching documents from cosmos DB I got result which contains $t and $v May be intermixing of data. How to parse proper Data .I have to fetch specific fields only which satisfies specific where condition.

```
//-----------fetching Documents from vuln_collection------------//
documentlist = client.CreateDocumentQuery(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("qualys", "vuln_collection"), "SELECT * FROM c").ToList();
//---------------//
```

Got result as

```
[..."$t":3,"$v":{"QID":{"$t":2,"$v":"6"},"VULN_TYPE":{"$t":2,"$v":"Information Gathered"},"SEVERITY_LEVEL":{"$t":2,"$v":"1"}..]
```

Comment: What's the API for this account?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to query the Cosmos DB MongoDB API using the SQL API SDK.

You should either migrate your data from the MongoDB API to a SQL API and use the same SDK or keep using the MongoDB API but use a MongoDB SDK like [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/) to query it.

Comment: Thanks for Information.As I am very new to this not having much Idea ..Is there any need for changing my c# code for fetching Documents.From the Visual Studio itself I have to fetch the Data properly .